# Solana Staking On Devnet

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

Getting error while delegating sol for staking on devnet

Trying to delegate sol on devnet

logs:

```
 SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: incorrect program id for instruction
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4243:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4205:20)
    at async Object.sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (.../node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:73:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111 failed: incorrect program id for instruction'
  ]
}
```

Wallet already has 2 sol and trying to stake 1 sol

Answer (score 2):

Devnet has very few validators, and thus very few vote accounts. When you delegate stake, you delegate to the vote account of that validator. Most likely, the vote account that you're trying to use does not exist on devnet.

If you want to stake on devnet, you'll have to choose one of the few validators that exist:

```
$ solana validators -ud
... lots of output ...
  7LH3HCmvnJRvHvzinbDerTNQ2GvLvdnukdx1dQ26aCFt  F95vVhuyAjAtmXbg2EnNVWKkD5yQsDS5S83Uw1TUDcZm   85%  186970328 ( -1)  186970294 ( -1)   0.00%   328645  1.14.10     18685.682466789 SOL (0.01%)
  HMU77m6WSL9Xew9YvVCgz1hLuhzamz74eD9avi4XPdr   4QUZQ4c7bZuJ4o4L8tYAEGnePFV27SUFEVmC7BYfsXRp   50%  186970329 (  0)  186970295 (  0)   0.00%   328483  1.14.11     23211.375784809 SOL (0.02%)
  dv2eQHeP4RFrJZ6UeiZWoc3XTtmtZCUKxxCApCDcRNV   i7NyKBMJCA9bLM2nsGyAGCKHECuR2L5eh4GqFciuwNT   100%  186970329 (  0)  186970293 ( -2)   0.74%   328100  1.14.11  38000616.134935230 SOL (24.99%)
  dv4ACNkpYPcE3aKmYDqZm9G5EB3J4MRoeE7WNDRBVJB   23AoPQc3EPkfLWb14cKiWNahh1H9rtb3UBk8gWseohjF  100%  186970329 (  0)  186970295 (  0)   0.78%   328462  1.14.11  38000746.551647313 SOL (24.99%)
  dv1ZAGvdsz5hHLwWXsVnM94hWf1pjbKVau1QVkaMJ92   5ZWgXcyqrrNpQHCme5SdC5hCeYb2o3fEJhF7Gok3bTVN  100%  186970329 (  0)  186970295 (  0)   8.14%   313125  1.14.11  38001301.134527914 SOL (24.99%)
  dv3qDFk1DTF36Z62bNvrCXe9sKATA6xvVy6A798xxAS   vgcDar2pryHvMgPkKaZfh8pQy4BJxv7SpwUG7zinWjG   100%  186970329 (  0)  186970293 ( -2)   0.84%   328136  1.14.11  38001935.839519262 SOL (24.99%)

Average Stake-Weighted Skip Rate: 2.63%
Average Unweighted Skip Rate:     15.79%

Active Stake: 152052703.61525476 SOL
Current Stake: 152046496.718881309 SOL (100.00%)
Delinquent Stake: 6206.896373432 SOL (0.00%)

Stake By Version:
1.14.11 -    5 current validators (99.98%)
1.14.10 -    1 current validators ( 0.01%)   2 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.13.4  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
1.13.3  -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)   1 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
unknown -    0 current validators ( 0.00%)  17 delinquent validators ( 0.00%)
```

Any of the non-delinquent ones at the bottom are good options for delegating.